# how to sort a dictionary in a dictionary by key

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

can you help me a little bit i'm stuck somewhere in my python code.
i'm sorry if my english is bad, but i'll try my best.

```
dict = {2: {20.934144973754883: 'red'},
      8: {36.431842803955078: 'blue'},
      9: {27.323692321777344: 'blue'},
     15: {37.194934844970703: 'blue'},
     18: {19.550689697265625: 'red'}}
y = []
x = []

for key,value in dict.items():
    y.append(key)

    for val,color in value.items():
        x.append(val)
        c.append(color)

plt.scatter(sorted(x),sorted(y),color = c)
```

To make a line of the data i sorted the x and y. But then when i scattered my plot, the colors where wrong. I know it's because i didn't sorted the colors. But if i try to sort them i fail. Because of the variable value:

```
value = {20.934144973754883: 'red'}
        {36.431842803955078: 'blue'}
        {27.323692321777344: 'blue'}
        {37.194934844970703: 'blue'}
        {19.550689697265625: 'red'}
```

You can't sort this.
please help me, i don't know what to do

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand the question, at least for me. Can you share the output you'd like to get for this sample?

Comment: Dictionaries are only sortable in Python3.6 I believe. There are ways to circumevent this like using `OrderedDict` from `collection` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value). In your case the value inside your dictionary would be the second dictionary.

Comment: Ordering of dictionaries in 3.6 is a side-effect of the C implementation and should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing [quantik's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315308/how-to-sort-a-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-by-key/44315638#comment75636258_44315308) to use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) makes sorting the keys possible and may yield the desired result:

```
import collections

d = collections.OrderedDict()

d[2]  = {20.934144973754883: 'red'}
d[8]  =  {36.431842803955078: 'blue'}
d[9]  = {27.323692321777344: 'blue'}
d[15] = {37.194934844970703: 'blue'}
d[18] = {19.550689697265625: 'red'}

y = []
x = []

for key,value in d.items():
    y.append(key)

    for val,color in value.items():
        x.append(val)
        c.append(color)

plt.scatter(sorted(x),sorted(y),color = c)
```

produces this output:

[image: colors scatter plot]

Comment: Add `c = []` to avoid an error.  I notice the last red point is not correlated with the data.  I expect a point at `(19.5.., 18)`  instead there is one around `(37, 18)`.

Answer (score 0):

> To make a line of the data i sorted the x and y. But then when i scattered my plot, the colors where wrong.

Your expected results are not clear, but I have the impression you interested in directly plotting the data.

> I know it's because i didn't sorted the colors.

If you are only interested in plotting data from the dictionary, sorting is unnecessary as we can unpack the dictionary in parallel.

> But if i try to sort them i fail.

Right now, you are unpacking parts of your data separately, which causes misalignment. You may be mistakenly tempted to sort the data to correct this misalignment.

Instead, try unpacking with `for` loops or a list comprehension (note `d` is used instead of the builtin `dict` variable):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#%matplotlib inline

d = { 2: {20.934144973754883: 'red'},
      8: {36.431842803955078: 'blue'},
      9: {27.323692321777344: 'blue'},
     15: {37.194934844970703: 'blue'},
     18: {19.550689697265625: 'red'}}

data = [(x, y, c) for y, v in d.items() for x, c in v.items()]

for x, y, c in data:
    plt.scatter(x, y, color=c)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can substitute the last two lines with the following, which unpacks all `x, y, c` data in parallel using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
xs, ys, cs = zip(*data)
plt.scatter(xs, ys, color=cs)
```